# Getting globals() of another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

The `globals()` function returns a dictionary of the variables defined in the current module.

Can I get such a dict for some other module?

Comment: `modulename.__dict__`, assuming that you've imported the module of interest.

Comment: @jasonharper not exactly the same though. me2 beats, why do you want to do this anyway? can you explain your use case?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, in what way is it "not exactly the same"?  A quick test of my assertion: `import __main__; __main__.__dict__ is globals()` produces `True`.

Comment: @jasonharper Testing using 2 modules (on py3) `module.__dict__` is much more populated with builtins etc.